# Apache strom - package backtype.storm.tuple does not exist

Tags: apache-storm

I'm trying the Storm analysis presents [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_storm/apache_storm_working_example.htm)

```
CallLogCounterBolt.java:4: error: package backtype.storm.tuple does not exist
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
```

Comment: Siva S, I am having same issue how did u fix it ? My apache storm version is "/opt/apache-storm-2.1.0"
javac 11.0.6
openjdk 11.0.6 2020-01-14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into similar problems with another old Apache Storm tutorial. It turned out to simply be because of the tutorial using deprecated classes from previous versions (0.9.6), while I was using newer ones (1.1.0). Therefore my suggestion is to either look through the newer libraries for corresponding resources in those and changing your library load statements accordingly, or checking that the dependencies that you are using are not masked by similarly named libraries.

Comment: yes you are right Kim Moritz Thanks. I start to use the library org.apache.storm. now its fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your Java classpath... which entirely depends on how you have setup your project. Rather than try to fix what you have I'll give you a suggestion.

If you're using Java, then the "normal" way to create storm topologies is using Maven which should work with whatever IDE you're using (Eclipse, Intellij, etc.).

Once you have a skeleton maven project setup, all you need to do is add the storm dependencies. For example:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>${storm.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Here is an [example POM file](https://github.com/kitmenke/storm-stlhug-demo/blob/master/pom.xml).

Comment: Thanks a lot Kit Menke. I just used maven properly and changed some older packages to new one. Its working fine.

Answer (score -1):

You should use newer Libraries in order to execute Since backtype is deprecated, Go through the Apache Storm javadocs [Apache Storm javadocs](https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.2.0/javadocs/index.html)